# how to remove the comma at the end of the last number?

Tags: arrays, c

For example, if I entered the array size to be 5, I will enter 5 elements. Then the elements should print out like n1,n2,n3,n4,n5

To visualize it better here is an example:

Input would be:
Enter array size: 4
Enter element 1: 7
Enter element 2: 14
Enter element 3: 21
Enter element 4: 28

And the output should be printed as:
{7,14,21,28}

But instead, the output that I get from the code is:
{7,14,21,28,}

There is a comma at the end of the number. But I want the comma to print in between the number and no comma at the end of the last number. I didn't know what to add or remove from the I the code I already have.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int size, i, element [100];
    
    printf("Enter array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
        printf("Enter element %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &element[i]);  
    }
    
    printf("{");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      printf("%d,", element[i]);
    }
    { printf("}");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%s%d", "," + !i, element[i]);`

Comment: @paddy First version segfaulted, right?

Comment: @paddy It seems a cleaner fix would be to use `"%c%d"`.  I like the `","[!i]` construct, but it probably only belongs in an obfuscated code contest.

Comment: This is a working example 

    int i = 0;
    printf("{");
    while(i<size){
        if(i<size-1)
            printf("%d,", element[i]);
        else  
            printf("%d}", element[i]); 
        ++i;
    }

Comment: Hehe yes indeed @AllanWind I wasn't thinking straight. As for %c, that doesn't work for this technique because that always prints a character, even NUL. But I agree it's obfuscated. More readable to use conditional operator. I do prefer to use the "start of loop" condition with leading separator, instead of "size-test" with a trailing one. Always felt more maintainable to me. Splitting into multiple print statements is unnecessary code duplication, and is troublesome with more complex outputs. Again, less maintainable.

Comment: If we answered your question make sure to accept the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you rewrite your loop to print a *leading* comma instead, and then print the first value before the loop:

```
if (size > 1)
    printf("{%d", element[0]);  // Array is not empty, print the first element
else
    printf("{");  // Empty array

// Since the first element have already been printed, start at the second
for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    printf(",%d", element[i]);
}

printf("}");
```

Answer (score 1):

I dare to suggest a logically readable code here.

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%d", element[i]);
    if (i != size - 1)
        printf(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By treating either the first (if you use prefix) or the last (if you use a suffix) element as a special case.

If you unroll @Someprogrammerdude's answer, say by printing 2 elements in each `printf()` for  1e8 elements (with value 0) they are are printed in ~4.055s with output redirected to /dev/null.

@Someprogrammerdude's answer original answer: 4.793s (1.182x).

@paddy's suggestion but more readable and flexible (with surprisingly a tiny performance edge over the original): 5.687s (1.402x).

```
    const char *sep[] = {",", ""};
    // ...
        printf("%d%s",  a[i], sep[i + 1 == LEN]);
```

My initial solution is 6.414s (1.582x):

```
        printf("%d%s",  a[i], i + 1 < SIZE ? "," : "");
```

Both of these benefit from just a single `printf()` statement while the faster solution require a 2nd conditional `printf()` either before or after the loop.

Comment: or `printf("%s%d", i ? "," : "", element[i]);`

Comment: if you don't mind can you explain?? I'm still learning so it would be greatly appreciated, if not then it's okay:)

Comment: ?: is a tertiary operator.  if i + 1 < size meaning all but the last element you use "," otherwise you use the empty string.